# iOS - trying to add the animation effect to the UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilabel, uicolor

Am trying to create the loading symbol like below GIF image. How can I achieve this animation?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this using Core Animation. You can create CAShapeLayer and animate its strokeStart and strokeEnd properties. I think this article may be helpful: http://calayer.com/core-animation/2016/05/22/cashapelayer-in-depth.html#stroke-start-and-end

Comment: @ Piotr Bernad : Thanks for your answer i will try the way you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different **UIProgressView** to achieve this animation.One UIProgressView should be transformed for reversing the start and ending point of progress bar. using the code

CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, progressbarLeft.frame.size.height);[image: Progress bar in ViewController]